# Unit Testing a Method That Uses a Context Manager

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a method I would like to unit test. The method expects a file path, which is then opened - using a context manager - to parse a value which is then returned, should it be present, simple enough.

```
@staticmethod
def read_in_target_language(file_path):
    """
    .. note:: Language code attributes/values can occur
    on either the first or the second line of bilingual.
    """
    with codecs.open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as source:
        line_1, line_2 = next(source), next(source)
        get_line_1 = re.search(
            '(target-language=")(.+?)(")', line_1, re.IGNORECASE)
        get_line_2 = re.search(
            '(target-language=")(.+?)(")', line_2, re.IGNORECASE)
        if get_line_1 is not None:
            return get_line_1.group(2)
        else:
            return get_line_2.group(2)
```

I want to avoid testing against external files - for obvious reasons - and do not wish to create temp files. In addition, I cannot use StringIO in this case.

How can I mock the file_path object in my unit test case? Ultimately I would need to create a mock path that contains differing values. Any help is gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I don't speak Python, so I'm likely to err in details)

I suggest that you instead mock `codecs`. Make the mock's `open` method return an object with test data to be returned from the `read` calls. That might involve creating another mock object for the return value; I don't know if there are some stock classes in Python that you could use for that purpose instead.

Then, in order to actually enable testing the logic, add a parameter to `read_in_target_language` that represents an object that can assume the role of the original `codecs` object, i.e. dependency injection by argument. For convenience I guess you could default it to `codecs`.

I'm not sure how far Python's duck typing goes with regards to static vs instance methods, but something like this should give you the general idea:

```
def read_in_target_language(file_path, opener=codecs):
    ...
    with opener.open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as source:
```

If the above isn't possible you could just add a layer of indirection:

```
class CodecsOpener:
    ...
    def open(self, file_path, access, encoding):
        return codecs.open(file_path, access, encoding)

class MockOpener:
    ...
    def __init__(self, open_result):
        self.open_result = open_result

    def open(self, file_path, access, encoding):
        return self.open_result

...

    def read_in_target_language(file_path, opener=CodecsOpener()):
        ...
        with opener.open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as source:
            ...

...

    def test():
        readable_data = ...
        opener = MockOpener(readable_data)
        result = <class>.read_in_target_language('whatever', opener)
        <check result>
```